# how to print multiple value on UILabel horizontally in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i now if i use this code it will print multiple value on label but in new line i not want like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);
    if ([displayTag length] > 0)
        labelSize = [displayTag sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return 24.0 + labelSize.height;
    }
    return 40.0;
}
```

this code will print vertical line but i want to print my value on label horizontally how to give multiple value for print on label horizontally on particular cell

for that i was create that but is not working
where i am wrong
this code in my custom cell

```
TagsLable= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, 15, 150, 21)];
            TagsLable.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16.0f];
            TagsLable.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
            TagsLable.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];



CGSize fontSize = [tagList sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17.0]];
        double finalWidth = fontSize.width *  UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        //double finalWidth = fontSize.width + self.numberOfLines;
        double finalHeight = self.frame.size.height;    //expected height of label
        CGSize theStringSize = [tagList sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(finalWidth, finalHeight) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        int newLinesToPad = (finalWidth  - theStringSize.width) / fontSize.width;
        for(int i=0; i<newLinesToPad; i++)
        {
            //tagList = [tagList stringByAppendingString:@","];
        tagList=[tagList stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@, ",tag.TagName];
        }
```

Comment: " multipla " ???? what do you mean actually ???  MULTIPLE or MULTIPLY ?

Comment: i mean MULTIPLE value should dispaly on lable please say how to do

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you post a picture of what you need?

Comment: What is the output of the second code block ?!

Answer (score 0):

What is **tag.TagName**.

Try this

```
tagList=[tagList stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@, ",tag.TagName];

NSString *tagList = [tagList stringByAppendingPathComponent:TagName.tag];
```